# Trying to add the quicklaunch back to a Decision Meeting Workspace

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I followed this post:http://blog.mattsampson.net/index.php/2010/12/13/quick-launch-on-new-web-part-pages?blog=1 which edits some 14 hive templates to remove all the code that hides the Quick Launch.  I used notepad++ to search all the files when I'd finished and I've definitely deleted the code.

But when I create a new Decision Meeting Workspace I still get no Quick Launch on the page.  Oddly enough I do get a quick launch showing on the page when I go into the Site Settings Page showing:

Site Content 
  Agenda 
  Attendees 
  Decisions 
  Document Library 
  Objectives 
  Tasks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the content place holder for the same is not set as hidden in master page

Comment: Not sure I understand.  So I should open the page that's not showing the quick launch in SPD?  And which content placeholder should I be looking for?

Comment: This is currently a bit of a roadblock for me.  Has anyone got a SP2010 meeting workspace with a quicklaunch that they could save as a template and send me: kevine@techie.com